# Return top level keys from map with a generalised type argument

Tags: dictionary, go, types, slice

I have the following method which returns all the keys from the `map`. But the argument it accepts must be of type `map[string]string`.

```
func GetAllKeys(m map[string]string) []string {
    keys := make([]string, len(m))
    i := 0
    for k := range m {
        keys[i] = k
        i++
    }

    return keys
}
```

How could I reuse this method, if I have a `map` but with a type `map[string]map[string]string`. Is there a way to generalize this method, because all it has to do is return the top-level keys from the map.

Comment: Note that iterating a map is non-deterministic. If you get a slice of keys, that slice will not be the same every time. In response to a post on code review, I quickly put together a generic map type that is safe for concurrent use, and allows for deterministic iteration, and decided to put it [on GitHub](https://github.com/EVODelavega/smap), feel free to have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Go 1.18+ you can write [generic functions](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Function_declarations) with [type parameters](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_parameter_declarations):

```golang
func GetAllKeys[K comparable, V any](m map[K]V) []K {
    keys := make([]K, len(m))
    i := 0
    for k := range m {
        keys[i] = k
        i++
    }
    return keys
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/jV2eNKjZmZu

Comment: It will be even more helpful if you could explain `[K comparable, V any](m map[K]V) []K`

Comment: `[K comparable, V any]` are __type parameters__, I've updated the answer with links to the relevant spec sections.